# Complex JOINS in Access SQL difficult to convert to JET OLEDB

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

I'm a long time follower of Stack overflow but this is my first post.  I'm hoping the community can help.

I have a successful Access Query that returns the required results - Perfect!
HOWEVER, I'm trying to return the same using OLEDB connection to the database within an ASP script.  This is all legacy stuff however we are allowing web access to this legacy information.

MS Access (2016) shows Query as this... (works)

```
SELECT [EventName] & ": " & [RoundCaption] AS RoundTitle, ChunkEntryTable.WinPos
FROM ((EventTable INNER JOIN EventRoundTable ON EventTable.EventId = EventRoundTable.EventId) INNER JOIN ((RoundHeatTable INNER JOIN ChunkTable ON RoundHeatTable.RoundHeatId = ChunkTable.RoundHeatId) INNER JOIN (EventEntryTable INNER JOIN ChunkEntryTable ON EventEntryTable.EventEntryId = ChunkEntryTable.EventEntryId) ON ChunkTable.ChunkId = ChunkEntryTable.ChunkId) ON EventRoundTable.RoundKeyId = RoundHeatTable.RoundKeyId) LEFT JOIN EventEntryMemberTable ON EventEntryTable.EventEntryId = EventEntryMemberTable.EventEntryId
WHERE (((EventEntryTable.Entry1Id)=[EntryId])) OR (((EventEntryTable.Entry2Id)=[EntryId])) OR (((EventEntryTable.Entry3Id)=[EntryId])) OR (((EventEntryMemberTable.MemberId)=[EntryId]))
ORDER BY EventTable.SortIdx, EventRoundTable.RoundId DESC , EventRoundTable.IsRepechage DESC;
```

Doing this in OLEDB.  Connection string as follows...

```
<%
' FileName="Connection_ado_conn_string.htm"
' Type="ADO" 
' DesigntimeType="ADO"
' HTTP="true"
' Catalog=""
' Schema=""
Dim MM_csresultdb_STRING
MM_csresultdb_STRING = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=xyz.mde;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxxxxxx;"
%>
```

Connection works perfectly but I can't seem to get the SQL command to work. I get "No value given for one or more required parameters".
NOTE: I have replaced [EntryID] in 4 places with a valid value and it works perfectly in Access just not outside of Access using OLEDB.  Here's what the SQL is I'm using...

```
SELECT EventTable.EventName & ": " & EventRoundTable.RoundCaption AS RoundTitle, ChunkEntryTable.WinPos FROM 
 ((EventTable INNER JOIN EventRoundTable ON EventTable.EventId = EventRoundTable.EventId) INNER JOIN
((RoundHeatTable INNER JOIN ChunkTable ON RoundHeatTable.RoundHeatId = ChunkTable.RoundHeatId) INNER JOIN
(EventEntryTable INNER JOIN ChunkEntryTable ON EventEntryTable.EventEntryId = ChunkEntryTable.EventEntryId) ON ChunkTable.ChunkId = ChunkEntryTable.ChunkId) ON ChunkTable.ChunkId = ChunkEntryTable.ChunkId)
ON EventRoundTable.RoundKeyId = RoundHeatTable.RoundKeyId) 
WHERE ((EventEntryTable.Entry1Id)=4741) OR ((EventEntryTable.Entry2Id)=4741) OR ((EventEntryTable.Entry3Id)=4741)
ORDER BY EventTable.SortIdx, EventRoundTable.RoundId DESC , EventRoundTable.IsRepechage DESC;
```

FOUND PROBLEM ** See answer below

Comment: This error usually occurs when you have a reference to what looks like a column but is not recognized as such.

Comment: They are all columns (Fields) in respective tables.  Double checked and works perfectly WITHIN Access. I suspect it's bracketing which is often slightly different using OLEDB drivers but I can't work it out.

Answer (score 1):

FOUND PROBLEM ** It's to do with this part of the SQL...

```
[EventName] & ": " & [RoundCaption] AS RoundTitle
```

Changed to

```
[EventName], [RoundCaption] AS RoundTitle
```

and it works but gives me two separate fields rather than the one concatenated field called "RoundTitle". So I'll join the two result fields during the display output rather than at the query stage.

Whew! That many days to figure out. Thanks to the comments that kinda steered me in that direction of the AS part of the statement.

Comment: . . Try using single quotes instead of double quotes for the string.